# c# syntax help -> What does Get<T>() where T means

Tags: c#

```
public static T Get<T>() where T : class
{
    string implName = Program.Settings[typeof(T).Name].ToString();
    object concrete = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(implName));

    return (T)concrete;
}
```

Please explain what does Get() where T means?

Welcome to put some reading URLs.

Comment: Just a note that this code looks very fragile to me. If you call it with a type that doesn't have a key in settings, it will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of a generic. 'T' represents a type.

For example:

```
string result = Get<string>();
```

Do a Google search on Generics. This will get you started:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: the first example will throw a compiler error because `int` is not a reference type. You should mention here the importance of the `where` constraint (or remove the first example)

Answer (score 3):

The `where T : class` puts a constrain on what types are allowed for `T`. This will

1. Give you an compiler error if you put in a wrong type
2. Give you access to access methods/properties or instantiate instances of T based on the constraint

So for your method this will produce an error if you call it like this `Get<int>()` since `int` is not a class.

```
public static T Get<T>() where T : class
{
    string implName = Program.Settings[typeof(T).Name].ToString();
    var implType = Type.GetType(implName);

    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(implType);
}
```

Comment: That will not compile.  No such overload exists.

Comment: ah yes... my bad, the T and type argument is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

This will constrain T to be a reference type in this particular case.